# How to invoke ssh exit from the C program under Linux Platform?

Tags: c, linux, ssh

My existing application has a customized CLI - command line interface. I am trying to call ssh from the existing application to the remote PC, which runs the same application, with a customized CLI. I can't use lib ssh to create a session but I want to use the existing Linux SSH application.
Here is the code, I have used to invoke ssh from one application residing in 1 PC to another PC. My problem is that how can I exit from the SSH. I see that invoking exit has no affects. What I should do any idea? Here is my sample program to do a SSH.

```
INT4 do_ssh(tCliHandle CliHandle, CHR1  *destIp)
{
    FILE *writePipe = NULL;
    char readbuff[1024];
    char cmd[1024];
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    int childInputFD;
    int status;

    memset(cmd,'\0',sizeof(cmd));

    sprintf(cmd,"/usr/bin/ssh -tt %s",destIp);

    /** Enable For debugging **/
    //printf("cmd = %s\r\n",cmd);

    /** create a pipe this will be shared on fork() **/
    pipe(fd);

    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }
    if( pid == 0 )
    {
        gchildPid = getpid();
        system(cmd);
    }
    else
    {
        /** parent process -APP process this is **/
        while( read(fd[0], readbuff, sizeof(readbuff)) != 0 )
        {
            CliPrintf(CliHandle,"%s", readbuff);
            printf("%s", readbuff);
        }
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Results - I can see that the ssh is invoked - I can type the password and can do the SSH on the remote PC application. But, I don't know how to exit the SSH session. What I should do to exit the SSH session?

Comment: Your loop `while (read(...) != 0)` will continue trying to read even in the event of errors. If you get an error reading you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: After the ssh is successful, how can I exit from the ssh session. I can't do exit because the ssh opens another custom application prompt. So, I can't call exit from the custom prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the child-process the standard output is not redirected to your pipe, you need to use e.g. [`dup2`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) like this:

```
dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
```

before the call to `system`.

And don't use `system` to execute the program, use the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) family of functions instead.

So the child process should look like this:

```
if( pid == 0 )
{
    // Make standard output use our pile
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    // Don't need the pipe descriptors anymore
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);

    // Execute the program
    execlp("ssh", "ssh", "-tt", destIp, NULL);
}
```

Also, in the parent process you need to [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for the child process once you're done.

---

And if you don't want to bother with pipes and processes and waiting and such, simply use [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead, which will handle it all for you and give you a nice `FILE *` you can use.

Comment: how will I exit from the ssh ?

Answer (score 0):

I want a ugly way to do so. But, in a large program we need to maintain a state table of what SSH Sessions are opened. Here is the program that will close the first SSH session.

```
int exit_ssh()
{
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];
    char sshCtrlword[512];
    printf("ssh Exit Invoked\r\n");
    memset(buff,'\0',sizeof(buff));

    if(!(in = popen("ps -A x |grep sshd |grep root |grep -v grep", "r")))
        if(!(in = popen(gsshCurrentSession,"r")))
        {
            printf("Error in Popen\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL)
        while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL)
        {
            //printf("%s\r\n", buff);
        }
    pclose(in);

    if( buff[0] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%s\r\n", buff);
        /** we have got something **/
        /** prepare control word **/
        sprintf(sshCtrlword,"kill -SIGTERM %s",buff);
        printf("%s\r\n", sshCtrlword);

        if(!(in = popen(sshCtrlword,"r")))
        {
            printf("Error in Popen() ctrl word..\r\n");
            return -1;
        }
        pclose(in);
    }

    return 0;
}
```